# What's the easiest way to convert a list of integers to a string of comma separated numbers in C#

Tags: c#, string, int

I'm looking for the one liner here, starting with:

```
int [] a = {1, 2, 3};
List<int> l = new List<int>(a);
```

and ending up with

```
String s = "1,2,3";
```

Comment: Sorry, I might have been unclear, I would like to convert `l`, not `a`.

So, to reword this, I would say: 
    List<int> l = new List<int>();
    l.Add(1);
    l.Add(2);
    l.Add(3);

And I would like to end up with `"1,2,3"`

Comment: Or say `List<int> l = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string.Join(",", l.ConvertAll(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

This is assuming you are compiling under .NET 3.5 w/ Linq.

Comment: In this case, the `ConvertAll` and `ToArray` methods have nothing to do with LINQ: they belong to the `List<T>` type itself. (But if you did want this code to compile with older versions of C# then you'd need to use `delegate` syntax rather than a lambda for your method argument.)

Comment: For .NET 4, you can just use `string.Join(",", l)`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx

Answer (score 9):

```
String s = String.Join(",", a.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string s = string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(a, i => i.ToString()));
```

or in .NET 4.0 you could *try* (although I'm not sure it will compile):

```
string s = string.Join(",", a);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  String.Join(",", l);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] array = {1,2,3};

string delimited = string.Join(",", array);
```

Comment: you can't string.join on an int[] array.  this doesn't compile.  EDIT:  hmm..  according to another post, you can, if you are in .NET 4.0.  You should specify that as a caveat in your post.

Answer (score 1):

```
l.Select(i => i.ToString()).Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + "," + s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
string s = a.Aggregate("", (acc, n) => acc == "" ? n.ToString() : acc + "," + n.ToString());
```

Comment: That's right, this will do the job, although it will be dramatically slower than the various `String.Join` answers on larger lists.

Answer (score -1):

I know you're looking for a one liner, but if you create an extension method, all future usage is a one liner.  This is a method I use.

```
public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string delimiter)
{
    StringBuilder joinedItems = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        if (joinedItems.Length > 0)
            joinedItems.Append(delimiter);

        joinedItems.Append(item);
    }

    return joinedItems.ToString();
}
```

For your list it becomes: `l.ToDelimitedString(",")`
I added an overload that always uses comma as the delimiter for convenience.

Comment: I'm not the downvote, but I will point out that this is slower than `String.Join`...